# Break statement for If contains and/or when reading from a lookup table

Tags: arrays, if-statement, vbscript, break, lookup-tables

I have a dilemma when reading from a very large look-up table (1000+ lines) that contains challenge phrases to determine if a file name (obtained from another delimited list) contains 3 of my 6 phrases. My If statement works only if it match's the challenge but I also need it to work if it only meets 1 specific phrase also from the look-up table. The look-up table example shows possible destination for only 1 user where I will have 100+ users to check against. I can get the correct result if it matches all of my challenges but if it does not it cycles through the rest of the lines containing the same user. Any suggestions to create a break would be much appreciated.

Below is the code I'm working with right now.

```
'Flags for files
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8

Dim strFDate: strFDate = DatePart("yyyy", Now) & Right("0" & DatePart("m",Date), 2) & Right("0" & DatePart("d",Date), 2) 'Formats date to YYYYMMDD
Dim strDate: strDate = Date 'Date with DD/MM/YYYY format

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fso2 = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")


'Check for %Client%.csv then record file data
Dim strTriggerName: strTriggerName = InputBox("Enter the User name for Row Count, ie. test", "Enter File Path and File Name")
Dim FileDest: FileDest = "C:\Test" 'Destination for moves and extracts must be in "C:\Test" format not ending with "\"


'Check if output.csv exist if not create it
    Set objFSO1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
        If objFSO1.FileExists(srtMovePath & "\output.csv")  Then
            'Msgbox srtMovePath & "\output.csv Exists"
        Else 
            Set objTXTFILE = objFSO1.CreateTextFile(srtMovePath & "\output.csv") 
            'Msgbox srtMovePath & "\output.csv Created"
            objTXTFILE.close
        End If

Set f = fso2.OpenTextFile("c:\output.csv", 2)


Set objFSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextTrigger = objFSO2.OpenTextFile("d:\File_Receipt_Triggers\" & strTriggerName & ".trigger", 1)
If (fso.fileexists("d:\File_Receipt_Triggers\" & strTriggerName & ".trigger")) Then


'Read csv for Client Name, File Name and File Path
Set objFSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO2.OpenTextFile("d:\File_Receipt_Triggers\" & strTriggerName & ".csv", 1) 

    Do until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
        Dim arrStr: arrStr = Split(objTextFile.ReadLine, "|")
        Dim strClient:      strClient = arrStr(0)
        Dim strFileName:    strFileName = arrStr(1)
        Dim strFullPath:    strFullPath = arrStr(2)


    'Compare file name to lookup table If strFileName contains (User & (C1 or C2) & (C3 or C4) & (C5 or C6)) then Destination
        Set objFSO8 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objMoveTable = objFSO8.OpenTextFile("d:\Move_Lookup_Table.csv", 1) 

    Do until objMoveTable.AtEndOfStream 

        Dim arrStr2: arrStr2 = Split(objMoveTable.ReadLine, ",")
        Dim User:           User = arrStr2(0)
        Dim C1:             C1 = arrStr2(1)
        Dim C2:             C2 = arrStr2(2)
        Dim C3:             C3 = arrStr2(3)
        Dim C4:             C4 = arrStr2(4)
        Dim C5:             C5 = arrStr2(5)
        Dim C6:             C6 = arrStr2(6)
        Dim Client:         Client = arrStr2(7)
        Dim Bank:           Bank = arrStr2(8)
        Dim OP:             OP = arrStr2(9)
        Dim Month:          Month = arrStr2(10)
        Dim Year:           Year = arrStr2(11)
        Dim strDestination: strDestination = arrStr2(12)
'ISSUE AREA

            If ((strTriggerName) = User ) and (Instr( Ucase(strFileName), C1 ) <> 0 or Instr( Ucase(strFileName), C2 ) <> 0) and (Instr( Ucase(strFileName), C3 ) <> 0 or Instr( Ucase(strFileName), C4 ) <> 0) and (Instr( Ucase(strFileName), C5 ) <> 0 or Instr( Ucase(strFileName), C6 ) <> 0) Then
            'msgbox strFileName & " is Good"
            '<Add code here>
            msgbox strFileName & " Should = " & " User: " & User & " and " & C1 & " or " & C2 & " and " & C3 & " or " & C4 & " and " & C5 & " or " &  C6 & " Client: " & Client & " Bank: " & Bank & " OP: " & OP & " Month: " & Month & " Year: " & Year & " Dest: " & "\\nas2\BAIArchive\BAI" & strDestination & Bank
            ElseIf ((strTriggerName) = User ) and Not 
            'msgbox strFileName & " does not match"
            '<Add code to here>
            End If

    Loop
Loop
End If
```

An Example of my look-up table is here:

> User,Contains1,Contains2,Contains3,Contains4,Contains6,Contains5,strClient,StrBank,strOP,strMonth,strYear,strDestination
>   test,DPB,DB,5,May,2013,13,BAI,TEST,DPB,May,2013,\2013May\DPB\
>   test,DPB,DB,11,Nov,2013,13,BAI,TEST,DPB,Nov,2013,\2013Nov\DPB\
>   test,DPB,DB,5,May,2014,14,BAI,TEST,DPB,May,2014,\2014May\DPB\
>   test,DPB,DB,11,Nov,2014,14,BAI,TEST,DPB,Nov,2014,\2014Nov\DPB\
>   test,DPB,DB,5,May,2015,15,BAI,TEST,DPB,May,2015,\2015May\DPB\
>   test,DPB,DB,11,Nov,2015,15,BAI,TEST,DPB,Nov,2015,\2015Nov\DPB\
>   test,NII,CTS,5,May,2013,13,BAI,TEST,NII,May,2013,\2013May\NII\
>   test,NII,CTS,11,Nov,2013,13,BAI,TEST,NII,Nov,2013,\2013Nov\NII_CTS\
>   test,NII,CTS,5,May,2014,14,BAI,TEST,NII,May,2014,\2014May\NIICTS\
>   test,NII,CTS,11,Nov,2014,14,BAI,TEST,NII,Nov,2014,\2014Nov\NIICTS\
>   test,NII,CTS,5,May,2015,15,BAI,TEST,NII,May,2015,\2015May\NIICTS\
>   test,NII,CTS,11,Nov,2015,15,BAI,TEST,NII,Nov,2015,\2015Nov\NIICTS\
>   test,SBB,SB,5,May,2013,13,BAI,TEST,SBB,May,2013,\2013May\SBB\
>   test,SBB,SB,11,Nov,2013,13,BAI,TEST,SBB,Nov,2013,\2013Nov\SBB\
>   test,SBB,SB,5,May,2014,14,BAI,TEST,SBB,May,2014,\2014May\SBB\
>   test,SBB,SB,11,Nov,2014,14,BAI,TEST,SBB,Nov,2014,\2014Nov\SBB\
>   test,SBB,SB,5,May,2015,15,BAI,TEST,SBB,May,2015,\2015May\SBB\
>   test,SBB,SB,11,Nov,2015,15,BAI,TEST,SBB,Nov,2015,\2015Nov\SBB\

Comment: Are you just after the [`exit do`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2at9t47.aspx) statement?

Comment: I would also recommend using [`ADODB`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25442358) to parse and query CSV files

Comment: I'm playing with a Do while statement now that may do the trick. Thanks for the advice.